# React using fetch to get token and checking response status?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch

I'm trying to check the status of a login via REST call and JWT token so that if that status is not ok then it'll return false, but this is what I'm getting.

```
export function login(data){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/token-auth/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => 
         console.log(json.token)  <= This prints correctly
    )
}
```

I tried adding in a check in this function, but then I no longer get the the token printed out

```
export function login(data){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/token-auth/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => {
         if(res.ok){
             console.log(res.json()) <= This prints something about promise
             console.log(res.json().token) <= this prints 'undefined'
         } 
    }).then(json => 
         console.log(json.token)  <= This prints 'undefined'
    )
}
```

Comment: You need to return `res.json()` from the first `then`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a catch block instead? Like so:

```
export function login(data){
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/token-auth/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => 
         console.log(json.token)
    ).catch(error =>
         console.log(error.response)
    )
}
```